# How to do Background Highlight in VSCode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, visual-studio-code

An essential part of web development with Ruby on Rails are templates. Within these, it is convenient that HTML and embedded Ruby code can be quickly distinguished.

In TextMate 2, by default, the Ruby code has a highlighted background, so although it may not look particularly attractive, it is swift to see.

I want to achieve something like this in VS Code.

[image: This is what I want in VS CODE]

Comment: use the extension **Highlight**

Comment: can you elaborate? I don't want to do it manually.
 How will that help?

Comment: do you want me to change your VSC setup and your settings, what does my comment has to do with `manually`

Comment: Highlight extension give you option to highlight a part of your code. This is not I want, What I want is wherever there is ruby code embedded in the HTML gets highlighted by default.

Comment: configure the extension such that it changes the background color of the RUBY parts

Comment: This is where I need help! 
If I knew how to do it, I wouldn't have posted the question here in the first place

If you could help me out with it, I would really appreciate it.

I feel we can do it with RegExp and Highlight extension, but I don't know how.

Comment: @rioV8 I need your help on the RegExp part, can you please help me out with that, please? 